# How to set jitter and loss rate of channel while using PointToPoint in NS3?

Tags: ns-3

I am new to NS3, learning NS3 from its tutorial. In the tutorial example [first.cc](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/first_8cc_source.html), it shows how to use `PointToPointHelper` and `UdpEchoClientHelper` to make a P2P test, we can find how to set `Data Rate` and `Delay` of channel. But I want to set jitter and loss rate of channel, is there any method?

```cpp
    PointToPointHelper pointToPoint;
    pointToPoint.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("5Mbps"));
    pointToPoint.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", StringValue ("2ms"));

    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Loss Rate of Channel

The good news is that [the tutorial](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/tracing.html?highlight=receiveerrormodel#main-program) already covers this

> ns-3 provides ErrorModel objects which can be attached to Channels. We are using the RateErrorModel which allows us to introduce errors into a Channel at a given rate.
>
> ```cpp
> Ptr<RateErrorModel> em = CreateObject<RateErrorModel> ();
> em->SetAttribute ("ErrorRate", DoubleValue (0.00001));
> devices.Get (1)->SetAttribute ("ReceiveErrorModel", PointerValue (em));
> ```
>
> The above code instantiates a RateErrorModel Object, and we set the “ErrorRate” Attribute to the desired value. We then set the resulting instantiated RateErrorModel as the error model used by the point-to-point NetDevice. This will give us some retransmissions and make our plot a little more interesting.

### Jitter

Jitter is a function of the processing and queuing delay encountered by the packets. It's not a quantity that you set directly. Rather, it is calculated based on measurements of latency of all packets across the life of a connection. The typical definition of jitter is the standard deviation of latency of all packets across the life a connection.

So, *ns-3* does not offer a way to set jitter directly (though it could since it's a simulator, but I digress).

But there is hope: if you want to change the jitter, you need to change the processing and queuing delays. Processing delay is a bit iffy, but queuing delays can easily be changed by choosing the type of Queue on the NetDevice. Refer to the `TxQueue` Attribute of the [PointToPointNetDevice](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_point_to_point_net_device.html).